# How to prevent compilation of passed lambda, if arguments are not references

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, std-function

In one of my projects I'm using a small utility function, which takes a `Message` struct and a lambda function, that modifies this message struct.

Now, I unintentionally passed a lambda without the necessary reference &. It perfectly compiles, but doesn't gave the desired output.

As for me, there should be one of the two following behaviors:

1. Forgetting to write `auto&`, but just `auto` should lead to compilation errors
2. Writing just `auto` should be interpreted as `auto&`.

It is possible to prevent compilation in case of a missing `&` or even better to interpret `auto` as `auto&` automatically?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct Message {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void changeMessage(Message& m, const std::function<void(Message&)>& messageModifier) {
    std::cout << "Message before:" << m.x << " " << m.y << "\n";
    messageModifier(m);
    std::cout << "Message after:" << m.x << " " << m.y << "\n";
}

int main(int, char**) {
    {
        std::function<void(int&)> f = [](int&) {};
        std::function<void(int)> g = [](int) {};
        f = g; // This compiles. 
    }

    {
        std::function<void(int&)> f = [](int&) {};
        std::function<void(int)> g = [](int) {};
        //g = f; // This does not compile. Makes perfect sense.
    }

    Message m{ 10,20 };
    {
        changeMessage(m, [](auto m) { m.x++; m.y--; }); // User unintentionally forgot &! Can I prevent this from compilation?
        std::cout << "Message outside: " << m.x << " " << m.y << "\n";
    }
    {
        changeMessage(m, [](auto& m) { m.x++; m.y--; });
        std::cout << "Message outside: " << m.x << " " << m.y << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: no, C++ does not work this way. The only way to prevent a callable object's argument from being a non-reference type is for something in the callable object itself to fail to compile if it were such a case. There are, of course, exotic solutions involving generating code or declaration using a script based on a template, that will make sure that the parameters have the correct types.

Comment: *"or even better to interpret `auto` as `auto&` automatically?"* - I'm afraid to think how much breakage would happen if that was possible. No, this is not better in any way. You are asking to replace a bug you can easily spot by an opening for bugs that may take hours or days to trace down. Dealing with dangling references is *way* harder.

Comment: Make `Message` a non-copyable object: `Message(const Message&) = delete;`.

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments. Really helped me to understand C++ a bit better again.

Comment: Technically speaking you can, with something like `!is_invocable_v<..., Message&&>` to ensure the lambda doesn't accept rvalues.

Comment: You could require the lambda to return the modified message. That would make the kind of mistake you worry about impossible. This is one advantage of using value semantics.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Many thanks for this advice. I will try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to prevent passing `Message` by value (and `auto` itself is never a reference) is to disable copy construction:

```
struct Message {
    Message() = default;
    Message(const Message&) = delete;

    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Another solution suggested by @[L. F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9716597/l-f) is to check that lambda doesn't accept rvalues:

```
template<class Fn>
void change_message(Message& m, Fn fn) {
    static_assert(!std::is_invocable_v<Fn, Message&&>);     
    fn(m);
}
```

Comment: And if you wish to make `Message` copyable, just not implicitly, you can use tag dispatch and overload on copy-constructor.

Comment: You can see the basic idea [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9VivL8). Probably should've made it `[[maybe_unused]] const implicit_copy_tag`, though.

Comment: @Fureeish, interesting idea, thanks! Curiously, if you have `void foo(Message)`, how can you call this function without using `foo({...})` syntax?

Comment: @Fureeish, you don't name the `implicit_copy_tag` parameter, so `[[maybe_unused]]` seems to be redundant, as well as `const`.

Comment: As for the attribute specifier, it's to prevent unsused-variable warnings. `const` is probably useless, yeah. Regarding the function, you can't. You would need to call it like `foo({msg, implicit_copy_tag{}});`.

Comment: @Fureeish, unused *named* variable.

Comment: Good call, forgot about that!